# C# if statment inside LINQ select clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq query and I need to have a value in my select clause based on whether or not a record exists in a list. Here is my query:

```
var records = (from il in itemList
        join ci in catalogueItemList on il.CatalogueItemID equals ci.CatalogueItemID
        join pd in publicationDataList on il.CatalogueItemID equals pd.CatalogueItemID
        select new { il.ItemID, pd.ISBN, ci.Title, ci.CatalogueItemID, il.LocationID, il.Missing,  }).ToList();
```

I have Dictionary called itemCheckoutDictionary, what I want in pseudo code is:

```
if (itemCheckDictionary.ContainsKey(i.itemID)) then "Checked Out" else "In"
```

I need that in my select clause, I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: which linq is this,  linq to Entities, objects, sql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often prefer to do it by using a small helper function:

```
var getStatus = new Func<int, string>(itemID => { 
    return itemCheckDictionary.ContainsKey(itemID) ? "Checked Out" : "In"; 
});

var records = (from il in itemList
    join ci in catalogueItemList on il.CatalogueItemID equals ci.CatalogueItemID
    join pd in publicationDataList on il.CatalogueItemID equals pd.CatalogueItemID
    select new { 
        // other properties
        Status =  getStatus(i.ItemID) }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 9):

Did you try [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)?

```
string s = itemCheckDictionary.ContainsKey(i.itemID) ? "Checked Out" : "In";
```

Comment: From your link: _" the conditional operator is commonly (albeit **incorrectly**) referred to as the ternary operator"_ ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter, the tricky thing is that Microsoft has used the term Ternary in their own *old* documentation, [Conditional (Ternary) Operator (?:)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: @TimSchmelter it seems to refer to the many different ternary operators and that the conditional would be the only one. It doesn't say that "ternary" is an incorrect term for the conditional operator. Alex isn't referring to it as "the" ternary operator.

Comment: @Default: it's not incorrect but it's not it's name. There can be multiple ternary operators(which  takes three operands) in a language and the _conditional operator_ is one of them.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, yes, Imagine the confusion if Microsoft adds another operator with three operands :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the if, you can use:

```
itemCheckDictionary.ContainsKey(i.itemID) ?  "Checked Out" : "In"
```

Comment: I need this in my select clause though, I can't put it in the select clause like that